# Sum of sequence involving random variables

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, random-variables

Suppose that $Y_1$, $Y_2$, $\dots$ is a sequence of independent uniform $(0,1)$ random variables, and define random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, ... as follows: $X_1$ = $Y_1$, and, for $n \geq 1$, $X_{n+1} = X_n$ or $Y_{n+1}$ according to whether $Y_{n+1} > E(X_n)$ or $Y_{n+1} < E(X_n)$, respectively.

**Question:** Does $\sum _n E(X_n)$ converge?

This is a puzzle given to me which I've failed to make any progress on. I suspect the answer is yes, but I'm stuck on how to rigorously justify it.

Comment: But when you compute $X_{n+1}$, the value of $X_n$ is known -- how does $\mathbb{E}[X_n]$ make sense in this context?

Comment: Why not? $\mathbb E[X_n]$ is a number, why can't it be used in defining $X_{n+1}$?  For example, $\mathbb E[X_1] = 1/2$, so $X_2 = Y_1$ if $Y_2 > 1/2$ or $Y_2$ if $Y_2 < 1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $EX_n=\mu_n$.

Note that $X_{n+1} = Y_{n+1}$ with probability $0< \mu_n < 1$, where $ Y_{n+1} \sim \text{Unif }(0, \mu_n)$, and $X_{n+1} = X_n$ w.p. $(1-\mu_n)$

Note also that $X_{n+1} < \mu_n$ and $\mu_{n+1} < \mu_n$, with strict inequality in both cases.

$X_{n+1}$ can be equal to $\mu_n$ only at the beginning of the sequence if the first element is repeatedly added (as $X_{n+1}=X_n$), but eventually, $Y_{n+1} < \mu_n$ will be added in the sequence as the last element. From then on, the above inequalities hold.

Express the mean as

$$\mu_{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+1}\mu_n + \frac{1}{n+1}X_{n+1}.
$$

Simple algebra shows that $\mu_{n+1} < \mu_n$ for either case, when $X_{n+1} = Y_{n+1} < \mu_n$, or $X_{n+1} = X_n < \mu_{n-1}$ .

Find the moment generating function, $M_{n+1}(t)=M_{n+1}$, of $X_{n+1}$:

$$
M_{n+1} = \mu_n \text{ MGF }(Y_{n+1} ) + (1-\mu_n) M_n,
 \text{where } \text{ MGF }(Y_{n+1}) = \frac{e^{\mu_n t} - 1}{\mu_n t}.$$

Using the fact that $M_{X}^{'}(t) | _{t=0} = EX$, find derivative of both sides of the above to get:
$$
\mu_{n+1} = \mu_n - \frac{1}{2}\mu_n^2
$$

Now, $\sum_{n \ge 1} X_n < 1 + \sum_{n \ge 2} X_n < 1 + \sum_{n \ge 1}\mu_{n+1}$

.....